# Why is RoundingMode is not resolving in Java 21?

Tags: java, bigdecimal, java-21

I am trying to work through a Spring lab and when I try to pull in Java 21, RoundingMode is not resolving.  I have been trying to research what I am doing wrong but I'm not finding anything seems to be off.  The class that I am trying to use is

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;  // <--this doesn't resolve
```

Error:

> "Cannot resolve symbol 'RoundingMode'"

This is the method that I'm trying to use RoundingMode as part of the BigDecimal.setScale.

```
private void initValue(BigDecimal value) {
    this.value = value.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
}
```

Everything that I'm reading RoundingMode is part of the JDK yet when I back down to Java17 then everything works just fine and the exact same import and usage for setting scale also resolves with no issues within my IDE.

Using IntelliJ 2022.3.3 as my IDE on MacOS.

Comment: What does "this doesn't resolve" mean exactly? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: this is is the error that I get from the IDE.  "Cannot resolve symbol 'RoundingMode'" for the import statement.  However when i switch to Java17, no issues.  To me it means that it doesn't exist in the implementation that I have downloaded from OpenJDK,  I'm using 21.0.2.

Comment: Post those details as edits to your Question, rather than Comments.

Comment: Where are you seeing that message? Doing what? And what ide and version are you using? Build system?

Comment: That code works for me in Java 22 pre-release. That enum was added way back in Java 5. So probably not a Java problem. Probably something screwed up with your IDE. First try a clean-and-build. If problem persists, clear caches within your IDE.

Comment: That code works for me in Java 22 pre-release. That enum was added way back in Java 5. So probably not a Java problem. Probably something screwed up with your IDE. First, restart IDE and maybe computer. Second, try a clean-and-build. If problem persists, clear caches within your IDE.

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Update IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 to 2023.3.4.  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.3/supported-java-versions.html#2023